# SQL Server - Distinct case in one column but last record in second column

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement (simple, but can't find simple solution) to fetch mobile number and unique transaction id (latest transaction would be good, but any transaction id is also ok)

**Sample Data**

```
Seq.    Mobile No.      Transaction No.
1       1234567890        ABC1234
2       2345678901        ABC2392
3       2345678901        ABC2782
```

I simply want to find mobile number 2345678901 and any of the one transaction, however latest would be good.

**Output**

```
Seq.    Mobile No.      Transaction No.
1       1234567890        ABC1234
2       2345678901        ABC2782
```

I know simply DISTINCT won't work, so not sure what's the best way to get the outcome.

I found a way to do it via sub-query, but I want to do it in single query for better performance.

Plz Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT Seq, MobileNo, TransactionNo
FROM (
  SELECT Seq, MobileNo, TransactionNo,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MobileNo ORDER BY Seq DESC) AS rn
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The above query will pick exactly one record per `MobileNo`: the one having the greatest `Seq` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by`.

```
select [Seq], [Mobile No], [Transaction No] from yourtable t1 
inner join 
(select [Mobile No], max([Transaction No]) as T_no from yourtable
group by [Mobile No]) t2 
on  t1.[Mobile No]=t2.[Mobile No] and t1.[Transaction No]=t2.T_no
```

Right query gives you latest `[Transaction No]` per `[Mobile No]` and left query is used only for finding matching `[Seq]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Transaction
(
    Seq VARCHAR(12),
    MobileNo VARCHAR(12),
    TransactionNo VARCHAR(12)
)

INSERT INTO #Transaction VALUES
 (1,'1234567890','ABC1234')
,(2,'2345678901','ABC2392')
,(3,'2345678901','ABC2782')

    SELECT DT.Seq,DT.MobileNo,DT.TransactionNo FROM
        (SELECT Seq,
               MobileNo,
               TransactionNo,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MobileNo ORDER BY Seq) AS Rn
         FROM
         #Transaction) DT
    WHERE DT.Rn = 1
```